# flutter slivers y drawer sin appbar ni icono de drawer

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer

en esta ocasión estoy intentando crear un drawer y lo puede esconder y mostrar programaticamente.
Actualmente tengo un CustomScrollView con un SliverAppBar y Sliver list. con un boton de busqueda flotante.
Ese boton de busqueda contiene un icono de menú que al ser presionado intento que muestre un drawer.
Para hacer esto, intento no usar un AppBar en el scaffold.
pong el drawer, pero me muestra el icono de la hamburguesa y no lo necesito así.

**Así como esta esta imagen deseo el resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Pero al poner un drawer dentro del scaffold sale así. OJO que no tengo ningún appBar**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aqui el código

```
  @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: null,
      drawer: Container(child: const CustomDrawer()),
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            elevation: 0,
            floating: true,
            pinned: true,
            title: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
              child: EntrySearchTextBoxWidget(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    FadeRoute(
                      page: const SearchPage(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                leftIconButton:
                    IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.menu)),
                label: const Text(
                  'Buscar equipo',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                  ),
                ),
                rightIconButton: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            toolbarHeight: 80,
            expandedHeight: 200,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            centerTitle: true,
            excludeHeaderSemantics: true,
            // collapsedHeight: 180,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/portada/teko.png',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              title: SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                // color: Colors.blue,
                child: Text(
                  'Recorrido de hoy ${tsToUi(format: 'EEEE, dd-MMMM-yyy')}',
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SliverListSearchHistoryItems(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Aqui en el código puse Drawer dentro de un container, haber si ayudaba pero nada. no funcionó.

Desde ya muchas gracias por su apoyo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El `SliverAppBar` es el que trae el ícono por default también, así que podrías asignarle un `leading` (widget que va a la izquierda) vacío.

```dart
      SliverAppBar(
              leading: const SizedBox.shrink(),
              ...
            )
```

Update (como mencionó Jamt0 en los comentarios)

Podemos indicarle al SliverAppBar que no asuma el leading por defecto, así:

```dart
SliverAppBar( 

    automaticallyImplyLeading: false, 

... )
```

Comment: Para ese objetivo es mejor usar
SliverAppBar(
               automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              ...
            )

Comment: @Jamt0 excelente, me había olvidado de ese param xD

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda, dejo como comentario que usando 
leading: const SizedBox.shrink() // creaba el espacio del icono del menu, pero no se mostraba.

y solo era suficiente con 
automaticallyImplyLeading: false

Muchas gracias a todos y a la comunidad..

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo que te serviria es esto, si agregas un drawe automaticamente agrega el icono asi no tengas appBar, de esta manera desactivas ese comportamiento

```
 Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false, // Oculta el botón mas a la izquierda
  ),
```